Что хранят sf::Texture, sf::SoundBuffer, sf::Font и sf::Music: данные или указатель?
Иными словами, имеет ли смысл передавать указанные выше объекты по указателю / ссылке или они сами являются указателями, т.е. их копирование ничего не стоит?

https://github.com/SFML/SFML

printf("%d\n", (int)sizeof(your_variable));
